# Using bash to take the average of all numbers on a line and all lines in a file

Tags: bash, unix, average

In essence, I have a txt file with a few thousand lines, each line containing 300 numbers. I need to take the average of the 300 numbers of each line, and then take the average of all of the averages in the file, a la;

```
0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7...
0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8...
0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9...

to

0.55
0.65
0.75

to

0.65
```

I've tried some bash scripts that I've found online, but they all concern finding the averages for columns, not for lines as a whole. My current strategy has been to do this operation with two scripts, one to find the average for each line, and a second to find the average of all of the lines together, but I haven't been able to figure anything out. I'm still rather new to bash and UNIX commands, so the solution is probably quite obvious, but I've yet to find it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Something like `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){lineTot+=$i; print "LineAvg=" lineTot/NF; gTotal+=lineTot} END{print "GTotalAvg=" gTotal/NR}' file` in one process ;-) Any errors are your opportunity to really understand the code ;-) . Work your way thru the [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) to understand meaning of `awk` internal variables like `NR` and `NF`. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash is a shell for high-level tasks, and is not the best choice for typical programming, reading files and doing arithmetics. [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) is the standard bash tool for this task. Here is a script for this:

```
> cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "," }

{
    sum = 0
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum += $i
    avg = sum / NF
    total += avg
    print "Line " NR ": " avg
}

END { print "Lines average: " total/NR }
```

Usage and output:

```
> awk -f tst.awk file
Line 1: 0.55
Line 2: 0.65
Line 3: 0.75
Lines average: 0.65
```

`FS` is the field separatot to be used. The `BEGIN {}` section is executed before reading the first line. awk is reading the file line by line and for every input line the main body `{}` is executed. The code inside there is self-explanatory and very similar to standard programming languages. After reaching the end of file the `END {}` is executed.

Comment: I agree `awk` is probably a good tool for the job; it'd what I'd use.  If the lines all have the same number of entries, your calculation is OK for the final average is OK.  If different lines have different numbers of entries, your final average is dubious — it should probably be `total_sum / total_num` where `total_sum += sum; total_num += NF;` should be added after the loop for each row.  Then again, what you've got might be exactly what's wanted, but it isn't usually going to be the same as `total_sum / total_num`.

Comment: Or the final average should be understood as an average _of lines_, not _of numbers_.

Comment: OP has asked to print the "average of all line averages" (not of all fields), so it prints that. In case we need the average of all fields, you are right, we have to keep the total NF.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do, with simple arithmetic and for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(cat data.txt) # Your primary data
all=0
l=0

for i in $data; do
    line=0
    k=0
    oldIFS=$IFS
    IFS=','
    for j in $i; do
        line=$(echo "scale=2; ($line+$j)" | bc)
        ((k++))
    done
    IFS=$oldIFS
    line=$(echo "scale=2; $line/$k" | bc)
    echo "Line $l: $line"
    all=$(echo "scale=2; ($all+$line)" | bc)
    ((l++))
done
all=$(echo "scale=2; $all/$l" | bc)
echo "Final result: $all"
```

Result:

```
Line 0: .55
Line 1: .65
Line 2: .75
Final result: .65
```

Note IFS variable here, use to change the separator in for loop: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS

Comment: There are various problems with this code. I would suggest to have a look at [BashFAQ:Don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Also if you plan to use `bc`, you could just do `echo "scale=2" ${i//,/+} | bc` which gives you the sum by replacing all commas with a sum. But it is cleaner to avoid `bc` for the sum and do it all in bash directly.